# How is it possible to assign "this" pointer to field?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, this

As far as I know, "this" pointer is the parameter that is inserted into function by Compiler like below :

```
class Sample {
private:
    int a;
public:
    void setA(int a) {
        this->a = a;
    }
};

Sample ob;
ob.setA(5); -> ob.setA(&ob, 5);

class Sample {
private:
    int a;
public:
    void setA(Sample* this, int a) {
        this->a = a;
    }
};
```

Btw, I found something confusing code that assigning the "this" pointer to const field. (Consult below)

```
class Test {
    int data;
public: 
    Test* const test = this;
    Test(int data = 1) : data(data) { }
    Test(Test &test) : data(test.data) { }  
};
(It has no compile Errors and runs well!)
```

If it is true that "this" pointer is conveyed via function, How can it be?
I have no idea..
Could you give me some advice please? I'm appreciate for your any replies.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The equals sign doesn't always mean assignment. It can mean many different things, depending on context. In the present case, it means "initialization".

Comment: Here's another confusing way that "assigns" a value to a constant variable: `const int a = 5;`

Comment: Well.. I'm just wanna know How can It works.

Comment: `Test* const test = this;` is not an assignment. It is an initialization.

Comment: @KerrekSB, why? It does compile OK.

Comment: Why are you trying to redefine class `Sample`?

Comment: @SergeyA: You're right, never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax:

```
Test* const test = this;
```

comes from C++11. It means "initialize `test` to `this` inside any non-copy constructor which does not already initialize `test` explicitly".

As a result, this code is executed inside the constructor, and `this` is perfectly  valid. However, the benefit of doing this sort of initialization is unclear, and dependening on the usage of `test` might be dangerous.

Comment: The word "explicitly" seems wrong there: it doesn't initialise `test` to `this` inside some constructors which already have initialised `test` implicitly: a compiler-generated copy constructor will happily copy the value of `test`.

Comment: @hvd, I didn't mean copy constructors, of course. Let me make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

The properties of the class (`Test.test` in this case) are initialized implicitly by code that is generated by the compiler.  There is a function, and it does receive the `this` pointer, but it's all generated by the compiler which is why you can't see it.